# How to make my iOS demo app as crash proof as possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a demo app using a very new API, so things may still not be stable.  What are the ways in Objective should I implement to make the app and code as crash proof as possible?

Note that I am not asking for practices to improve stability, but more like ways to catch runtime exceptions, etc. and turn it into a noop so the demo doesn't get interrupted even if something goes bonkers (including any close source API lib I use misbehaving).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this article: "Handling unhandled exceptions and signals" http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html
It shows a solution to recover after an uncaught exception. But don't forget to read the limitations part. It's a risky thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar with an unstable stuff. Swizzled some risky API methods at runtime (the SDK was closed source), and wrapped the original invocations into a `@try` block. I could even send GA events on exceptions as well to track down crashy stuff.

May use https://github.com/eppz/eppz.swizzler (see tests for usage). With https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser you can beautifully inspect closed source libraries.

---

Or you may define a global exception handler using [**`NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler).

Comment: Thanks Geri.  I am also interested in the general case of how to make my app crash proof when exception is thrown.  Any idea?

Comment: May use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` then https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: Continue running after an exception seems not a good idea in general to me. You cannot predict any behaviour then, so probably it will present further errors as well.

Comment: Thanks, I only intend to institute this in demo - not in production code.  So the downside is not a concern for me.